# SelectDataKey in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I grab the value from the SelectedDataKey function from the ButtonField? It keeps coming back null. Right now I've managed to create a foreach loop to actually see what value are available but this method is not ideal.

This is the ASP code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" Width="1100px" SelectedRow="hotelId" GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" DataKeyNames="hotelId" OnRowCommand="GridViewResults_RowCommand" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="thumbNailUrl" DataImageUrlFormatString="https://media.expedia.com{0}" HeaderText="Image" />
                        <asp:BoundField  DataField="name" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField  DataField="locationDescription" HeaderText="Location" />
                        <asp:BoundField  DataField="hotelRating" DataFormatString="{0}/5" HeaderText="Hotel Rating" />
                        <asp:BoundField  DataField="lowRate" DataFormatString="£{0}" HeaderText="Lowest Price" />
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="View" DataTextField="hotelId" HeaderText="View Hotel" ButtonType="Button" DataTextFormatString="{0}" />
<%--                        <asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields="hotelId" HeaderText="View Hotel" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?apikey=5qjdrl3pjpj8f8gj6u7b40ofjk&sig=117f9d785e142c4be4285799ab8608b4&cid=488640&minorRev=99&customerUserAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0&customerIpAddress=84.246.168.11&locale=en_US&currencyCode=GBP&hotelId={0}" Text="View" />--%>
                    </Columns>
                   </asp:GridView>
```

This is the logic for the for each loop, but I want to grab the value which has been selected.

```
    protected void GridViewResults_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewResults.Rows)
                {
                    string _hotelId = GridViewResults.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                    var searchListRequest = new RestRequest("/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info", Method.GET);

                        string hotelId = _hotelId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `CommandName="hotelId"` in your `ButtonField` and inside your `GridViewResults_RowCommand` do the following.

```
        protected void GridViewResults_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "hotelId")
            {
                int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                int hotelId = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewResults.DataKeys[rowindex].Value);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.
Regards!